# Kendo DropDownList Tab to Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have an interesting requirement.  For the Kendo DropDownList, I need to have the tab key act as the enter key, while also continuing the tabbing through the control.  The sequence should be:

In the dropdownlist, the up/down arrow can navigate the list of items.  On clicking tab on an item, it should select the item in the list, and tab to the next control in the browser tab order.

Is that possible, maybe by injecting a tab action in one of the dropdownlist events?

Comment: Interesting question. Check [this out](http://dojo.telerik.com/uqOMi). The point now is how to move focus to next element, which can be done by two ways: *Caching* all form inputs in a collection to find the next element, or look after next el *in loco* at the event . The default tab behaviour in the widget seems to work as a `select()` by itself. You only need to move the focus.